# How to make a generator point / coordinate for a shape?

Tags: vb.net, generator, coordinate

I am currently creating a program using Visual Basic dot Net, which is to create a coordinate generator application for a shape. Example shape circle, the input is the length of the diameter then the coordinates will be obtained anywhere.
Does anyone have a reference to my problem?
I really appreciate if somebody can help me. Thank You

Comment: So you want only a circle or any other shape, have you started any code at all, or you want a full code? Because there is not a lot of info above!

Comment: For any other shape...   I still make it and have not done it yet. If there is a full code, can you share with me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: So you need to know only about the generator, you don't need the drawing functionality?

Comment: Yes, I want to create an application generator shape, which the end result is known point coordinates on the shape.

The case example is like this:
Assumed initial coordinates point to create a shape is (x, y) = (0,0).
When I will make a circle then I just put the diameter only, it will get the shape of the circle, along with the coordinate point that can form the circle.
Another example is when I will create a rectangular shape. Then just enter the length (x) and height (y) of the rectangle, then it will form a rectangle below the point coordinates.

Comment: But the problem is how to determine the location of the coordinate point of the shape.
Is there someone who has already done it? As a reference for me to complete this work. 
Thank You.